# NodeJS - Returning object from function overwrites previous declaration of that object

Tags: node.js, object, overwrite

I have object in my main.js:

```
var Status={
   prop1:'',
   prop2:'',
   prop3:'',
   prop4:''
};
```

Then I have a function (in another .js file) that calculates `prop2`, `prop3` and `prop4` like so:

```
function CalculateProperties() {
   var returnToMain={
      prop2:'',    //note that props in returnToMain have same names as in Status
      prop3:'',
      prop4:''
       };
   returnToMain.prop2=**some_calculations**;
   returnToMain.prop3=**some_calculations**;
   returnToMain.prop4=**some_calculations**;

   return returnToMain;

}

module.exports = CalculateProperties;
```

From main.js I call it like this:

```
Status = CalculateProperties();
```

I would expect that it leaves `prop1` alone and it overwrites `prop2`, `prop3` and `prop4`, but it overwrites the objest as a whole, so after I run it I end up with:

```
Status={
   prop2: 'Calculated_Value',
   prop3: 'Calculated_Value',
   prop4: 'Calculated_Value'
};
```

instead of:

```
Status={
   prop1: 'Original_Value',
   prop2: 'Calculated_Value',
   prop3: 'Calculated_Value',
   prop4: 'Calculated_Value'
};
```

How do I make it so it overwrites only properties with same names and leaves others alone? Thanks.

Comment: Use `Object.assign(status, CalculatedProperties())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge your objects using Object.assign

```
Status = Object.assign(Status, CalculateProperties());
```

es6 analogue

```
Status = {...Status, ...CalculateProperties()}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new object in `CalculateProperties` and returning it. 
In your `main.js` you are assigning this returned value to `Status` which is a different object.
Hence now `Status` points to the new object which doesn't know anything of the older properties.

You have three options:

a. Pass the `Status` object to `CalculateProperties` and update it.

b. Assign it to new variable say `CalculatedValues`  and copy over relevant properties to `Status`

c. Merge the objects using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [lodash.merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge).